# See the definition of a cursor

Tags: postgresql

From doing `select * from pg_stat_activity;`, I can see that some process is using a cursor.  The query column look like this:

```
FETCH FORWARD 50000 FROM "db"
```

Is there any way to see the SQL that was used to define `"db"`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pg_catalogs.pg_cursors` view.

```
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# DECLARE "db" CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM book_lines;
DECLARE CURSOR
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_cursors ;
 name |                     statement                     | is_holdable | is_binary | is_scrollable |         creation_time         
------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------------
 db   | DECLARE "db" CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM book_lines; | f           | f         | t             | 2016-03-05 21:17:01.565456+08
(1 row)
```

Note that it shows the whole statement defining the cursor, not just the query that underlies the cursor. I don't know of any way to get just the cursor's query, so you'd probably have to do text processing to get that.

Comment: This only works if you are inside the same connection as where the cursor is declared since `pg_cursors` is backend-local.  @CraigRinger, I just found [your other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24521268/2223706) saying it's not possible to see the cursors of other connections.

Comment: Well, of course. A cursor in another backend is irrelevant and meaningless; you can't access it in any way, so there's no point being able to list it.

Comment: It was relevant to me because I needed to debug what part of our application was calling it as well as whether it was fine to terminate it.

Comment: I see, so you had "FETCH ..." or something in `pg_stat_activity` and you wanted to know what the definition of the cursor being fetched from was, because you suspected load/performance/locking issues resulting from that cursor and wanted to know if you could terminate the session with the cursor. That makes some sense. I'd probably attach gdb to the session in that case, but that's not exactly a user-friendly approach, so that's an interesting point - pg_stat_activity can show cursors from outside the session but there's no way to see their definitions.